# GeoPandas input file to shapefile with coordinate system information

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, geopandas

I have written some Python code to convert different input files to a shapefile using `geopandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point #convert to 3D GeoPandas GeoDataFrame

#-------INPUT FILE TO SHAPEFILE---------
input_file = "C:/input_file.xyz" # hard-coded for the minute - to be changed
file_extension = os.path.splitext(input_file)[-1].lower()

if file_extension == ".xyz":
    df  = pd.read_table(input_file, skiprows=2, sep=r'\,|\t', engine='python', names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]

elif file_extension == ".txt" or ".csv":
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\,|\t')
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
        

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df.apply(lambda row: Point(row.x,row.y,row.z), axis=1))

gdf.to_file("C:/new_shapefile.shp") # hard-coded for the minute - to be changed

print("Shapefile Created!")
```

The code successfully runs and creates a shapefile, but I'm wondering is there any way to automatically include the coordinate system information? The coordinate systems will obviously vary depending on the input file.

Comment: @user2856 even with doing this my shapefile is located in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

Set the CRS when you create the [GeoDataframe](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html):

```
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=etc..., crs="the CRS of your xy coordinates")
```

Note, this requires you know the CRS your coordinates are in and it doesn't reproject them to a new coordinate system.