# Converting x/y in Pandas DataFrame to lat/long

Tags: python, shapefile, latitude-longitude, pandas, xy

I have written the following Python code to convert various input files into a shapefile using Pandas.

The coordinates of the input file are x,y which is what my shapefile outputs to, but I would like to add in some code which converts the input file to lat/long.

However, I'm unsure how to go about this

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point 


input_file = "...input_file.csv" 
file_extension = os.path.splitext(input_file)[-1].lower()
output_file = input_file[:-4]


if file_extension == ".xyz" or ".asc":
    df  = pd.read_table(input_file, skiprows=2, sep=r'\,|\t', engine='python', names=['x', 'y', 'z'])
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]

elif file_extension == ".txt" or ".text" or ".csv":
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, sep='\,|\t')
    df.columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
        

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=df.apply(lambda row: Point(row.x,row.y,row.z), axis=1,), crs='EPSG:4326')

gdf.to_file(f"{output_file}.shp") 
shapefile = f"{output_file}.shp"

print("Shapefile Created!")
```

Comment: yes sorry, I should have said I'd like the z value to be maintained

Comment: You need [`gdf.to_crs(4326)`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) but you must already have set the CRS of the x,y coordinates like I commented on your last question [`gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=etc..., crs=the CRS of your coordinates)`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/430586/2856) because GeoPandas can't reproject if it doesn't know the current CRS.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I recommend the [`os.path.splitext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) function from the `os.path` module to get `file_extension` and `output_file` in a bit more elegant way:

```py
from os.path import splitext

input_file = '.../input_file.csv' 
output_file, file_extension = splitext(input_file)
print(output_file, file_extension)
```

Let's assume there is a *.csv*-file called *'points.csv'*, see image below:

[image: input]

On this stage the [`GeoDataFrame`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html) will be created:

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from os.path import splitext

absolute_path_to_file = '.../input_file.csv'

file_name, file_extension = splitext(absolute_path_to_file)

if file_extension == ".txt" or ".text" or ".csv":
    df = pd.read_table(absolute_path_to_file, sep=',')

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['x'], df['y'], df['z']), crs='EPSG:25832')

print(gdf)
```

that results in (keep in mind that the point's geometry representation is [`POINT Z`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-warehouse?topic=SSCJDQ/com.ibm.db2.luw.spatial.topics.doc/doc/rsbp4120.html)):

```
   id          x           y      z                                  geometry
0   1  513072.05  5402445.83  250.0  POINT Z (513072.050 5402445.830 250.000)
1   2  513212.88  5402852.80  245.0  POINT Z (513212.880 5402852.800 245.000)
2   3  513733.74  5403658.99  239.0  POINT Z (513733.740 5403658.990 239.000)
```

Now it is possible to get latitude, longitude, and altitude using:

- the GeoPandas's [`to_crs()`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html) function as was suggested by @user2856:

  ```py
   import pandas as pd
   import geopandas as gpd
   from os.path import splitext
   from pyproj import CRS

   absolute_path_to_file = '.../input_file.csv'

   file_name, file_extension = splitext(absolute_path_to_file)

   if file_extension == ".txt" or ".text" or ".csv":
       df = pd.read_table(absolute_path_to_file, sep=',')

   gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['x'], df['y'], df['z']), crs='EPSG:25832')

   crs = CRS.from_string('EPSG:4326')
   gdf = gdf.to_crs(crs=crs)

   print(gdf)

      id          x           y      z                              geometry
   0   1  513072.05  5402445.83  250.0  POINT Z (9.17792 48.77488 250.00000)
   1   2  513212.88  5402852.80  245.0  POINT Z (9.17985 48.77854 245.00000)
   2   3  513733.74  5403658.99  239.0  POINT Z (9.18697 48.78578 239.00000)
  ```
- Pandas and a custom function with the pyproj's [`Transformer`](https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/api/transformer.html#pyproj-transformer) class:

  ```py
    import pandas as pd
    from os.path import splitext
    from pyproj import CRS, Transformer

    def xyz_to_latlonalt(x, y, z, crs_in, crs_out):
        crs_from = CRS.from_user_input(crs_in)
        crs_to = CRS.from_user_input(crs_out)
        proj = Transformer.from_crs(crs_from, crs_to, always_xy=True)
        coordinates = proj.transform(x, y, z)
        return coordinates

    absolute_path_to_file = '.../input_file.csv'

    file_name, file_extension = splitext(absolute_path_to_file)

    if file_extension == ".txt" or ".text" or ".csv":
        df = pd.read_table(absolute_path_to_file, sep=',')

    df['lat'] = df.apply(lambda row: xyz_to_latlonalt(row['x'], row['y'], row['z'], 25832, 4326)[0], axis=1)
    df['lon'] = df.apply(lambda row: xyz_to_latlonalt(row['x'], row['y'], row['z'], 25832, 4326)[1], axis=1)
    df['alt'] = df.apply(lambda row: xyz_to_latlonalt(row['x'], row['y'], row['z'], 25832, 4326)[2], axis=1)

    df = df.drop(['x', 'y', 'z'], axis=1)

    print(df)

       id       lat        lon    alt
    0   1  9.177920  48.774878  250.0
    1   2  9.179850  48.778536  245.0
    2   3  9.186966  48.785778  239.0
  ```